# Окно из интерактивных элементов при большом количестве элементов отображает некорректно

Tags: c#, windows, gui, desktop

[image: Сводная форма - правильное отображение]

У меня есть база данных достопримечательностей, гостиниц, сервисов и т.д. по всему миру. В своё приложение я добавил форму, в которой отображается сводный перечень, например, только достопримечательностей (на скрине), или только гостиниц. Форма содержит элемент `TableLayoutPanel`, в ячейки которого добавлены динамически создаваемые дочерние элементы `Label`, в дальнейшем я хочу расширить этот список за счет рисунков и других элементов. Эти элементы кликабельны, т.е. если кликнуть на слове "Кировский район", то в приложении откроется карточка Кировского района Екатеринбурга.

На скрине выше открыта сводная форма по одному региону, и дочерних элементов у `TableLayoutPanel` немного. Но если отобразить подобную сводную форму, к примеру, достопримечательностей всего мира, т.е. с большим количеством дочерних элементов, то этот список отображается не полностью, коряво, надписи наслаиваются друг на друга, а иногда приложение просто зависает. На скрине ниже видно, что перечень достопримечательностей Гаврилово-Ямского района сверху "зарублен", но самое главное, что туда попали строки из другого района (при не очень дотошном знании географии можно обратить внимание, что форты Кронштадта не относятся к Гаврилово-Ямскому району), т.е. элементы `Label` просто перемешались.

[image: Неправильное отображение]

А ниже - пустота, хотя пространство на форме выделено:

[image: Неправильное отображение 2]

Хочу задать вопрос, как отобразить в проекте Приложение Windows на платформе .NET 5.0 форму с большим количеством хотспотов (т.е. интерактивных кликабельных элементов), при этом работающую исправно? Одно из предположений: не хватает памяти для всех этих элементов, тогда есть ли возможность решить эту задачу не через `TableLayoutPanel`, а, например, через какое-то подобие веббраузерного элемента или другие, не столь "ресурсо-жрущие" элементы? Другое предположение: `TableLayoutPanel` принимает ограниченное количество дочерних элементов. Какое предположение правильное, сказать не могу, пока я вижу, что форма просто лагает.

PS. Использование компонента Panel не устранило проблемы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка в строке № 123.

Comment: Нужен код! Как вы работаете с этим TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: Единственное, что я могу предположить, не видя код, это ограничение размеров контролов WinForms, равное 32768 или 65536 пикселей. Это ограничение WinAPI, на котором основаны ВинФормы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я просто добавляю элементы: tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label1). Т.е. сначала я запрашиваю инфу из БД, выделяю в ней единицы (в данном случае это регионы и достопримечательности), создаю лейбелы для этих единиц и добавляю на панель

Comment: Почему не использовать DataGridView, например? Быстрее, без тормозов и с нормальным отображением.

Comment: Не поленился. Попробовал создать TableLayoutPanel с динамическим добавлением простых Label`ов. В моем случае нормально отображается 1425 меток (с тормозами при прокрутке). 1426-я уже встает коряво. Последующие просто не отображаются (но пустое место в конце добавляется). С DataGridView такого нет.

Comment: а зачем Вам сразу пытаться отобразить все метки? Отобразите 100 видимых или около того, продумайте пагинацию или частичное отображение.

Comment: Повторяю: нужен код! Сколько у TableLayoutPanel колонок? С какими настройками он создан? / Если колонка всего одна, то зачем вообще этот контрол? Вся его суть в `Table` - табличном отображении. Почему не взять обычную панель?

Comment: У вас простой вертикальный стек элементов, `FlowLayoutPanel` подойдет легко. Table - это когда несколько колонок и несколько столбцов, или нужно позиционирование в процентном соотношении от ширины формы для этих колонок/столбцов.

Comment: @aepot `FlowLayoutPanel` не подошло. Всё превратилось в шахматную доску. Записи должны вертикально друг за дружкой идти

Comment: Так вы настройте ее как вертикальную. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection#system-windows-forms-flowlayoutpanel-flowdirection

Comment: @aepot, использование простого элемента Panel, кстати, тоже не дало положительный результат. Картинка в постскриптуме вопроса

Comment: Как я уже писал, контролы имеют лимит размеров 32768 (16 бит). Это ограничение WinAPI. Причём это не обязательно размер самого контрола, но и размер внутренней области, которая прокручивается, `DisplayRectangle`. 1425 лейблов высотой 23 пиксела по умолчанию как раз дают это значение. Всё что больше - отсекается. Это никак не обойти в Винформах.

Comment: Тут нужно использовать динамеческую подгрузку. `DataGridView` имеет виртуальный режим. С ним можно получить комфортную работу.

Comment: Кстати, у `TableLayoutPanel` двойная буферизация отключена по умолчанию. Желательно её включить. / Также нужно вызывать метод `SuspendLayout()` перед добавлением большого количества элементов на контрол, а после этого - `ResumeLayout()`.

Comment: Ещё на заметку: например, `ListBox` имеет методы `BeginUpdate()`, `EndUpdate()` - следует их использовать. В целом, применение подобных методов (где они имеются) сильно улучшает производительность и отзывчивость контролов.